# Plotting with a time axis in Matlab using dateTick and dateNumbers

Tags: matlab, plot

I am making a script to plot burst signal events on a pesudo-waterfall.
With x-axis being frequencyand y-axis being time I plot a line from
[event-frequency event-startTimeStamp] to [event-frequency event-endTimeStamp]
to represent each burst.

I am using the following code:

```
tstart = datenum(0,0,0,0,0,0);
tend = datenum(0,0,0,0,0,1);
timeInterval=tend-tstart;
xlim([0 10]);
hold on;

cla;
timeAxis = linspace(tstart, tend, 100);
set(gca,'YTick',timeAxis,'FontSize',6,'YDir','reverse');
datetick('y','HH:MM::SS.FFF','keepticks');
plot([1 1],[tstart tstart+timeInterval/4]);
plot([2 2],[tstart+timeInterval/8 tstart+timeInterval/2]);
tstart=tstart + timeInterval;
tend=tend + timeInterval;
```

The paragraph from the cla can be repeated to plot 'signals' in later time increments of one second.  This works fine.
If I change the first two lines to the following: edit: using this value cuz it's the timestamp of the first burst

```
tstart = datenum(2011,6,13,15,10,40.999);
tend = tstart + datenum(0,0,0,0,0,1);
```

The plot looks horrible and the labels get messed up into a black mess.  I can't work out why it's happening.  Anybody know?
(copy-pastable code if you wanna try it out)

-Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Try not showing all the tick marks, instead only a subset of them. Something along the lines:

```
set(gca,'YTick',timeAxis(1:10:end))
```

Also read up on [DATETICK](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datetick.html#f20-740135) options: `'keepticks'` and `'keeplimits'`

Comment: I tried your suggestion about plotting less points.  It doesn't change the result for plotting the second situation I described (using the real start and end times).  What really confuses me about this is that changing ONLY the times has this effect.  The timestamp format doesn't change depending on the time so the axis labels shouldn't take up more space for a later time.